# Count number of elements in list stored at different position in java

Tags: java, list

How can I count number of elements stored in different position in a list.
Eg :

```
final List<String> products = new ArrayList<>();
products .set(2,"Top");
products .set(5,"Bottom");
products .set(7,"Pants");
products .set(10,"Skirt");
```

Count should be 4.

Is there any short solution for this.

Comment: This will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because list does not have any element and you are directly setting value at index `2`.

Comment: Java won't let you have a list with "skipped indices."  The List API only works if your indices are 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1.   This won't work in the first place.

Comment: @pnegi Consider using `Map<Integer, String>` instead of `List<String>`

Comment: Then how to do this when I have to store elements at different positions and I can also count the no. of elements in this?

Comment: @pnegi Misha already told you.  Use a `Map`.  Its `size()` method will tell you the total number of entries.

Answer (score 2):

[`E set(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method replaces element of specific index. If list does not have element at that position it will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Moreover, if you want to find number of elements in list you can simply use `size()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
`int c=products.size();`
In your case,`c` will be assigned a value `4` since you have 4 elements in your list.

Note:
The first index of your array list is `0` and it goes in order-0,1,2....etc.
You need to place something at the indices 0 and 1 before going to  2.You can't skip to 2.

In your case,it will throw an error because you are replacing the element at a position/index using the `set(int index,string new)` without assigning an element to that position.
The positions are already empty and so there is nothing to replace.

Use `products.add(int index,String new)` to assign a value to a particular index.Replace `set` with `add` in your code.Begin with index 0.
Finally,use the `product.size()` to get the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure appropriate to your task is [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).  You can use it like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> products = new HashMap<>();
products.put(2,"Top");
products.put(5,"Bottom");
products.put(7,"Pants");
products.put(10,"Skirt");

String p10 = products.get(10);          // "Skirt"
int productCount = products.size();     // 4
boolean has3 = products.containsKey(3); // false
```